# Keep track of Main-Task

Tags: python, celery

Suppose i have Report-Building-Workflow roughly described as follows

```py
@shared_task
def report_builder(*args, **kwargs)
  return chain(
    group(gather_data_from_service_a.s()....),
    merge_data.s(),
    export_to_html.s(),
    export_to_pdf.s(),
    store_pdf_on_s3.s(),
    ).apply_async()
```

Called by `task = report_builder.s().apply_async()`

How do I keep track of the main task (here: report_builder)? Problem is the main-task succeeds short after its been called (because all it does is returning an AsyncResult).

What i want to achieve is to poll status-information about the main-task, transitioning from PENDING to STARTED to (SUCCESS or FAILURE) and in the end get the s3-location of the last task in the chain as a result of the main task.